# Using input tag helper in asp.net core - the "value" is empty

Tags: asp.net-core, viewmodel, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am brand new on .net 5 asp tag helpers. I have models like these:

```
public class MyForm
{
    public String Url { get; set; }
    ...
}


public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Url { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Seller username")]
    [Required]
    public String SellerName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In my controller I got and URL value for example https://myshop.com/item?id=1234

```
public IActionResult AddLinkWizardSecond(MyForm form)
{
   var model = new MyViewModel() {
     Url = "https://anotherShop.com/index.html",
     SellerName = "test user 123",
   };
   return PartialView("myView", model);
}
```

Where my view looks as:

```
@model MyViewModel
<input asp-for="Url" readonly>
<input asp-for="SellerName">
```

It is said that the tag helper for input element renders all necessary tags including value tag also. Several examples (on the internet) shows that the rendered html contains <input value="...somevalue...". But - for me this is odd - the rendered html I got in my browser looks as:

```
<input name="Url" id="Url" value="https://myshop.com/item?id=1234" ... />
<input name="SellerName" id="SellerName" value="" ... />
```

There must be reason behind this - but I cant catch it. Could somebody give me some ideas why the url contains the posted data instead of the new one, and why the seller name value is empty when I fill these properties? I tried to put the values to ViewBag and ViewData before - but none of them are working:

```
...
this.ViewData["SellerName"] = model.SellerName;
return PartialView("myView", model);
```

Is this too much I ask for the tag helpers? They cannot use the current values? Then where the posted value comes from?

Apologizes for the dummy question :( Any advice is greatly welcome which can help me out from the deep swamp of despair where I am now :(

Comment: Don't just return `View()`, follow the Post Redirect Pattern and return a `RedirecToAction` instead. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mxmissile :) The first post comes from a modal dialog, this 2nd returns with the 2nd wizard page. Re-posting causes no problem.

Comment: Sorry @mxmissile - I must apologize. You gave the solution to my question - but I still cant catch the main point... Is this pattern so deeply involved to asp.net mvc so without using this pattern this simply wont work? This was working in net framework based mvc before...

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct this is a design choice in the framework. You can read about why it was made, some theory, and also a few work arounds in [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/20/aspnet-mvc-postbacks-and-htmlhelper-controls-ignoring-model-changes).

For example, calling `ModelState.Clear();` in your Post action will display the behavior you are looking for.

However, its standard "practice" to use the [Post Redirect Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) regardless, which solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time Sire! I really appreciate it! Helper a lot! Now I really understand what happens and why. Now I'm wondering why this is not clarified by the documents on the MS sites about tag-helpers... Or am the one who cannot found it? :(